# How to filter results by value in multiselect field?

Tags: jss, graphql

I have many blog pages that are of type BlogArticlePage, all of these pages can have many "tags" selected through a MultiList field.

In the JSS GraphQL Schema it looks like this:

```
type BlogArticlePage implements ..., Item {
  ...,
  body: TextField
  image: ImageField
  summary: TextField
  title: TextField
  tag: MultilistField
}
```

Tag contains items that are of type ContentTag.

```
type ContentTag implements Item {
  ...,
  tagtitle: TextField
}
```

I have been able to get a GraphQL query to return all blogs and their tags.

Query:

```
{
  search(rootItem:"/sitecore/content/Home/Blog") {
    results {
      items {
        item {
          ... on BlogArticlePage {
            id
            browserTitle: field(name:"browserTitle") {
              value
            }
            tag: field(name:"tag")  {
              ...ContentTags
            }  
          }
        }  
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
}

fragment ContentTags on MultilistField {
  tags:targetItems {
    ... on ContentTag {
      id
      tagtitle {
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "results": {
        "items": [
          {
            "item": {
              "id": "4008F0AA67CD444AAF168AEA33BB1CCF",
              "browserTitle": {
                "value": "I am blog 1"
              },
              "tag": {
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "id": "B5099C4F122141B9A6468180299F8F4E",
                    "tagtitle": {
                      "value": "True stories"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "C335F690644B4396A9E11E787E19573A",
                    "tagtitle": {
                      "value": "Inspriational"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "item": {
              "id": "7F25D333C9C644C2821BCAC98058E81F",
              "browserTitle": {
                "value": "I am blog 2"
              },
              "tag": {
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "id": "B5099C4F122141B9A6468180299F8F4E",
                    "tagtitle": {
                      "value": "True stories"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "totalCount": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am now trying to work out how do I filter these results so I only get blog articles that match a certain tag? For example "Give me all blogs that have a tag with a tagTitle of True stories".

I have tried using the `fieldEqual` function of search, trying on the tagTitle with a string and also on the tag using GUID (I found that example [here](http://www.stockpick.nl/english/content-tagging-jss-graphql/)).

```
{
  search(
    fieldsEqual:[
      {name:"tagTitle", value:"True stories" }
      #{name: "tag", value:"b5099c4f122141b9a6468180299f8f4e"}
    ]
...
```

In both cases I get zero results. I have proven that I can use `fieldEqual` to filter on the `browserTitle` field value, so it seems to me an issue with how I am trying to filter a MutltiList value.

The documentation for JSS GraphQL querying is really poor, what I have learnt so far has come from blogs and here. Has anyone tried something similar before or have any ideas that could help me out?

Comment: I think you are getting zero results because there is no blog that has tag value of "True stories" only. I think the blogs that do have this value might have other values as well. So in essence what you are looking for is a "contains" match instead of an "equals" match.

Comment: I get what you are saying ... but I am not sure how to do a contains. Again the documentation is really poor, I am going on blog articles that suggest you can do a wildcard type search eg: "fieldsEqual:[
      {name: "tag", value:"*b5099c4f122141b9a6468180299f8f4e*"}
    ]" ... but that also didn't work.

Comment: Hi @mbla-sc - did you get any fix for this issue?